# Can I manage sdks and jres in a central place, shared between aplications?

Tags: java

As a java developer I use some software also written in java (Intellij, maven...) and also others (dbeaver) and I think my disk has repeated downloads of the java platform.

Is it possible to set up a central, personally managed location for these artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SDKMAN!

[SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) is your friend. This tool is a well-designed collection of shell scripts for:

- Learning about what versions of Java are available from each of several vendors.
- Downloading and installing those JDKs.
- Tracking your currently installed JDKs.
- Setting the current default JDK to use.

This tool works for Unix-oriented OSes. This includes macOS, Linux, Cygwin, Solaris, and FreeBSD.

Scripts are written in [*bash*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), but run in [*zsh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) too.

If your favorite JDK vendor is not listed within SDKMAN!, ask the vendor to submit the metadata for their releases.

Besides JDKs for Java, SDKMAN can also manage installs for [a few dozen other tools](https://sdkman.io/sdks) including Gradle & Maven, Spring Boot, and Apache Tomcat.

## IntelliJ

The [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) recently gained a [feature to download and install a JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/download-jdk/) from various vendors, on your command.

Comment: Might mention sdkman can manage a lot of other software besides jdks (https://sdkman.io/sdks)

Comment: @NathanHughes I added your point and link to the Answer. Thank you.